# tables displaying up to down,i need left to right

Tags: php

```
 <?php 
      include("config.php");
      $sql="SELECT * from product_tbl where prod_status=1 order by prod_id desc LIMIT 6";
      $result=mysql_query($sql);
      while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<table class='products' border=1 width=180>";
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo "<center>";
        echo $row['prod_name'];
        echo "</center>";
        echo "</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo "<img src='".$row['prod_img']."' height=200 width=178/>";
        echo "</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo "<center>";
        echo "Rs.".$row['prod_price'];
        echo "</center>";
        echo "</td></tr>";
        echo "</table>";
      }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears as  **nonsense**.

Comment: sorry,my code not display correctly.

Comment: Read about what `td` and `tr` are about.

Comment: how can i edit that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you try `td` style with `float:left` or you need row is left you try `tr` style `float :left`

Comment: you tr to add inline style with tr or td tag.

Comment: Welcome :) @Daivyesh Jesadiya